# I have difficulty initialising enum in constructor in C++

Tags: c++, enums

I am using enum to initialise the different genders.
So my problem is that a do not know what  exactly to put in this constructor.

```
class CPerson {
private:
    char* Name;
    enum class Gender { Male = 0, Female = 1 };
    Gender sex;
public:
CPerson(const char* szName, Gender s)
        :Name{ nullptr }
    {
        Name = new char[strlen(szName) + 1];
        strcpy(Name, szName);
        sex =s ;
    }

void main(){
Cperson("Simon",?????);
}
```

Comment: You need to make the enum public

Comment: your enum is private in CPerson, it cannot be used out of it, why to do that ? Out of that what about to use a `std::string` for the *Name* ? Also why *Name* rather than *name* ?

Comment: That's an assignment in the constructor. You can only initialize members in the initializer list.

Comment: It is a university homework and they want to use ``char*`` rather then ```std::string```

Comment: Unfortunate. Beware of the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Shouldn't you at least ask what the object's pronouns are before assigning it a gender?

Comment: If you cannot use `std::string`, you ought to make your own `belin::string` class that handles the memory management of your simple string class instead of having CPerson be responsible for that too.  Separation of concerns.

Comment: Okey I will do that thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your enum is part of the class, you need to reference the class name to get access.

And since you've made `Gender` a class instead of a simple enum, you'll have to reference it too.

```
CPerson("Simon", CPerson::Gender::Male);
```

Plus as noted in the comments, you need to make the enum public.

Comment: @FredLarson I thought that individual enum names were also defined in the enclosing scope.

Comment: @FredLarson oh that's funny, my eyes completely glossed over the word "class".  Twice.

Comment: Yeah, I know the feeling.

Answer (score 0):

To instantiate your Enum Class you should go for something like :

```
CPerson("Simon", CPerson::Male);
```

As a side note, if your Enum members will follow the order 0,1,2...., you don't need to explicitly type so :

```
enum class Gender { Male,Female};
```

should be enough.

Comment: The enum is private

Comment: This is enum class, the names do not leak to enclosing scope. You must refer to them as `CPerson::Gender::Male`